# NetworkStatsManager not returning mobile data usage (API 33)

Tags: java, android, permissions, network-traffic, android-13

Dear Stack Overflow community,

I'm having an issue with my Android Java code where I'm unable to get mobile data usage using the following code, but I'm able to get Wi-Fi usage. I'm using API 33, and I have also included the requested permission in my code.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
```

```
 protected boolean hasUserPermission() {
        try {
            PackageManager packageManager = getContext().getPackageManager();
            ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(getContext().getPackageName(), 0);
            AppOpsManager appOpsManager = (AppOpsManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
            int mode = appOpsManager.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS, applicationInfo.uid, applicationInfo.packageName);
            return (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```
protected List<InternetUsage> getNetworkUsageByDay() {
        NetworkStatsManager networkStatsManager = (NetworkStatsManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.NETWORK_STATS_SERVICE);

        int[] networkTypes = new int[]{NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI, NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR};

        List<InternetUsage> networkUsageList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = -29; i <= 0; i++) {

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, i);
            Date date = cal.getTime();
            String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(date);


            long wifiRx = 0;
            long wifiTx = 0;
            long mobileRx = 0;
            long mobileTx = 0;


            for (int networkType : networkTypes) {
                NetworkStats.Bucket bucket = null;
                try {
                    bucket = networkStatsManager.querySummaryForDevice(networkType, "", getStartTimeForDay(date), getEndTimeForDay(date));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "getNetworkUsageByDay: ", e);
                }

                if (bucket != null) {
                    if (networkType == NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) {
                        wifiRx = bucket.getRxBytes();
                        wifiTx = bucket.getTxBytes();
                    } else if (networkType == NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) {
                        mobileRx = bucket.getRxBytes();
                        mobileTx = bucket.getTxBytes();
                    }
                }
            }


            InternetUsage networkUsage = new InternetUsage(formatFileSize(wifiRx+wifiTx), formatFileSize(mobileRx+mobileTx),dateString);

            networkUsageList.add(networkUsage);
        }
        Collections.reverse(networkUsageList);
        return networkUsageList;
    }


    private long getStartTimeForDay(Date date) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        return cal.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    private long getEndTimeForDay(Date date) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
        return cal.getTimeInMillis();
    }
```

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_NETWORK_USAGE_HISTORY"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

I have tried to debug it myself, but I couldn't find a solution. Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you so much for your time and help in advance.